# Android Ndk Error No rule to make target

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android.mk, ndk-build

I am try to build Android Cpp project using Ndk.

when i build app its only generate jni folder files

cannot generate jni sub folder files

i got this error

make: *** No rule to make target `src/main/jni/src/main/jni/A/B/Helper.cpp', needed by`build/intermediates/ndk/obj/local/armeabi/objs/demo/src/main/jni/A/B/Helper.o'.  Stop.

```
TOP_LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := demo

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp d.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/B/Helper.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -lGLESv2 -lEGL -landroid -lOpenSLES -lGLESv1_CM -lz

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/B

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1):

The file names that are listed in **`LOCAL_SRC_FILES`** are *relative* to **`LOCAL_PATH`**. ALso, you can define this list on multiple lines, but by appending the list, not replacing it.

So, your **Android.mk** file should probably look like this:

```
TOP_LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := demo

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp d.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += A/B/Helper.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -lGLESv2 -lEGL -landroid -lOpenSLES -lGLESv1_CM -lz

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/B

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Note that the list **`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`** should use full paths.

Comment: LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  How to include header file from different directories.

Comment: E.g. `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += D:/projects/demo/include`

Comment: Can i use this type of includes LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/B \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/C \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/D